# Change label in masterpage from content page on button click

Tags: c#, master-pages

I have to change the text in a label on a master page from a content page on button click but here is the wrinkle... it is during a forms login redirect. Is there a way to accomplish this? Here is my code, everything is set up correctly I think the issue is the redirect which is changing the label back to the default text value.

### Login Code

```
    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         var result = Utilities.AuthenticateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);


                if (result.Authenticated)
                {
                    this.User = result;



                    DDC master = (DDC)Page.Master;
                    master.lblLogin_Text = result.FirstName + ' ' + result.LastName;

                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(result.Username, false);
                    return;
                }
            }


    }
```

### Master Page

```
public partial class DDC : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    public string lblLogin_Text
    {
        get { return lblLogin.Text; }
        set { lblLogin.Text = value; }

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Session` to keep track of your authentication result.  Since you don't have the class name in your sample code, lets assume its `AuthenticationResult`.

In your login page, do the authentication, then set a session variable that the `MasterPage` can read:

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = Utilities.AuthenticateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    if (result.Authenticated)
    {
        Session["AuthenticationResult"] = result;
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(result.Username, false);
    }
}
```

In your `MasterPage`'s `Page_Load`, have it check the `Session` variable and set the `Label` text:

```
public partial class DDC : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string lblLogin_Text
    {
        get { return lblLogin.Text; }
        set { lblLogin.Text = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var result = (Session["AuthenticationResult"] as AuthenticationResult);
            if (result != null && result.Authenticated)
            {
                this.User = result;
                lblLogin_Text = String.Form("{1} {2}, result.FirstName, result.LastName);
            }
            else
            {
                lblLogin_Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is using a web farm so session won't work. I wish it was not but thats the enivornment I have to work with.

Comment: There are methods to persist session data in that case.  But if it is still not an option, I would suggest doing your authentication logic in your masterpage, then hiding the control after authentication has finished.  Don't use a separate login page.

Comment: I suppose I could use a State Server, I've never used SQL for session data before though.

Comment: You should definitely look into it.  Think of how ineffecient it is going to be to have to reauthenticate the user after every page visit.  I suppose you could use cookies for this, but I would stay far far away from doing authorization via cookies.